# Unparseable date en local, pero si en AWS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws

Muy buenas resulta que tengo el siguiente código, el cual cuando lo pruebo en AWS corre correctamente, pero cuando intento correrlo en Local se rompe, la verdad no tengo idea de que podrá ser, no se si alguien me puede ayudar descifrando este misterio.

El código ese el siguiente.

```
@Override
    public LocalDate getDateItem( String Id){
        AcortadorUrlParaHistoricos ItemAcortador = getItem(Id);
        String dAcortador = ItemAcortador.getDate();
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        LocalDate DateAcortador = null;
        try {
            LOG.info("Convirtiendo fecha del ID: ->"+Id);
            DateAcortador = formato.parse(dAcortador)
                    .toInstant()
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toLocalDate();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return DateAcortador;
    }
```

Y me devuelve el siguiente error en local, pero en AWS funciona correctamente.

2022-02-21 10:41:42.099  INFO 9824 --- [p-nio-80-exec-6] s.c.a.c.AcortadorUrlHistoricosController : Objeto optenidonull
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Oct 29 23:10:13 GMT 2021"
at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese formato no es correcto para esa cadena de entrada. Sospecho que "en AWS" tampoco esta funcionando igual o el locale de la máquina es diferente y hay magia adicional que "hace que funcione".

Posiblemente sirva si usas algo como

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                            Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Aunque, si usas Java8 o superior, podrías dejar de usar la aproximación vieja y desaconsejada para usar las clases nuevas en `java.time`:

```
String input = "Sat Jun 01 12:53:10 IST 2013";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

De paso, le indicas qué locale usar y dejas de depender de la configuración del servidor.

Edito: Para esa diferencia que dices, puedes tener dos LocalDate, luego usar Period y obtener lo que necesites de allí

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 4);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2020, 10, 10);

Period dateDifference = Period.between(date1, date2);

System.out.print(period.getYears() + " years,");
System.out.print(period.getMonths() + " months,");
System.out.print(period.getDays() + " days");
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ayudaste muchísimo <3, ve me queda una duda respecto a lo ultimo que mencionas, el método .toLocalDate() lo estoy usando porque luego quiero sacar los días entre dos fechas, la que obtengo con este método y la fecha actual que obtengo con LocalDate.now() y saco los dias con DAYS.between(date1, currentDate). 

Se puede aplicar el toLocalDate a el método que mencionas?

O me aconsejarías otra manera de sacar esta diferencia entre las fechas? 

Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda nuevamente <3 <3